# Should user-specific properties be returned from an authenticated REST API endpoint?

Tags: rest, architecture

In my system, if I GET an endpoint `api/businesses/1`, details about a business is returned (Address, Opening Hours etc.) as JSON. If an access token is passed in the header of the request, then the server can identify the user making the request, and can supplement the returned data with user-specific data (Address, Opening Hours, PLUS whether the user has bookmarked this business).

My question is - should authenticated/non-authenticated properties be returned from one request like this, or should they be split into two separate requests? (`/api/business/1` for Address and Opening Hours, `api/user/123/bookmarks` for the user's bookmarked businesses). The latter approach means that I can cache the first request response, which would be useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case it could be better to split it into two methods

```
/api/business/1
```

and

```
api/user/123/bookmarks/
```

Reasons for that:

- It makes API cleaner - each API method does well defined job
- It is easier to test your API, because you'll get rid of the state here (by the state I mean using token to get a user). So by passing the same business/user id you can expect to always getthe same result
- Yes, you can cache it

Comment: Thanks, makes sense to me too.